# Finding action handlers in Ember debugger

Tags: ember.js

I'm finding that when I put my form's actions handlers into the controllers `action` property as is now recommended these handlers no longer are visible within the Ember debugger. Is that correct or am I missing something?

To illustrate ... I have the following controller:

```
App.UomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    testing: null,
    actions: {
        addUom: function() {
            var router = this.get('target');
            router.transitionTo('uoms.new');
        }       
    }
});
```

The property `testing` shows up clearly enough in the debugger but not actions and consequently no way to get to the `addUom` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `actions` is managed by [Ember.ActionHandler](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ActionHandler.html). At the moment, it will copy that info in the `_actions` property. So controller._actions.someAction, will return the action handler.

For example:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        lorem: Ember.K,
        ipsum: Ember.K,
        showActionsInController: function() {            
            alert(Ember.keys(this._actions)); // will display 'lorem,ipsum,showActionsInController'
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle with this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/8xfRJ/

Comment: Ok, so I assume because the `_actions` property has a preceding underscore it doesn't show up in the debugger window but if I then dump this to the global $E variable I can find the `_action` property and it does indeed have all the action handlers I've defined. Would be nice to have this more visible in the debugger but at least now I know where to look. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I think in the future this will be just `actions`, the `_actions` is used to preserve backward compability.